El emulador (AVD) de android no carga
tengo problema con el emulador nose porque no carga
solo se queda diciendo esperando la conexion ya lo desistale , reinstale me asegure de no este bloqueado x el antiviruz pero sigue sin funcionar , ayuda porfavor

¿Probaste a borrarlo totalmente, desde la línea de comandos?

No, podrías decirme como porfa

¿Qué sistema operativo estás usando?

usa sistema windows 11


Desde la terminal de Android Studio escribe este comando: adb devices. Deberías ver el nombre de tu emulador o una lista en caso de tener más de uno. 2. Luego ejecuta este comando adb -s nombreDelEmulador emu kill cambiando la palabra nombreDelEmulador por el nombre que apareció cuando ejecutaste el comando indicado en (1). Eso detendrá el emulador y ahora podrás borrarlo desde la opción Device Manager de Android Studio. Cuando el emulador da problemas conviene borrarlo totalmente para reiniciarlo desde cero. Otra cosa, verifica que tu equipo cumple con los requisitos mínimos.


La opción de borrado aparece haciendo click en los tres puntos verticales, al lado del nombre del emulador.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
